# Prevent subloop repeating within jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

Im trying to build a simple webtool using jQuery. I'm new using jQuery, so don't laugh ;-). It needs to show a car based on the selection menu and per car it needs to show and hide tinted windows while clicking on the windows. Its all working, but after switching cars the show and hide function of the selected windows are repeating on click (show/hide/show/hide) after clicking on them again.

The more you switch within the select options, the more it repeats. How do i prevent this repeat from happening?

It also needs to generate a price, right now its hardcoded within the window selection, but i need to have the prices different per car per windows, but this will come later. First i need to prevent this loop from happening.

```
<div id='tintbuilder-container'>

        <div id='carselector'>
                <h3 style='color:#FFF'><center>Voertuigselectie:</center></h3><br>
                <form class='selectcar'>
                     <select id='carselection' name='typecar'>
                        <option value=''>Selecteer je auto</option>
                        <option value='sedan'>Sedan</option>
                        <option value='station'>Station</option>
                        <option value='hatchback'>Hatchback</option>
                        <option value='coupe'>Coupe</option>
                        <option value='overig'>Overig</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
        </div>


        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var carlist = [ "sedan", "station", "hatchback", "coupe", "else" ];
        jQuery.each( carlist, function( i, val, list ) {
            $('#carselection').change(function () {
                    $('.hidecar').hide()
                    $('#' + this.value).show();
          $("#tintbuilder-container").append("<div style='display:none;' id='"+ val + "' class='car hidecar'><div class='selectionlist'></div>"
        + "<div class='selectionprice'>Huidige selectie: &euro;<span class='"+ val + "price'>0</span>"
        + "<div><h3>Selectie</h3><ul class='" + val + "list'><ul></div></div>");

        var win = [ val + "rearwindow", val + "quarterwindow", val + "reardoorwindow", val + "frontdoorwindow" ];

        jQuery.each( win, function( i, win ) {
        $("#"+val+"").append("<a><div id='"+win+"-container'><div class='tint' id='" + win + "'></div></div></a>");
         $("#"+val+"").on("click", "#"+ win +"-container", function() {
             if( $("li").is("."+ win + "listitem") ) { $("."+ win + "listitem").remove();}
             else { $("." + val + "list").append($("<li class='" + win + "listitem'>" + win + "</li>"));}
             $count = $("."+ val + "price");
             var $this = $(this);
             $("#"+ win +"").fadeToggle();
             if ($("."+ win + "on")[0]){
             $this.removeClass(""+ win + "on");
             $count.text(function(idx, txt) { return +txt - 200;})
             } else {
             $this.addClass(""+ win + "on");
             $count.text(function(idx, txt) { return +txt + 200;})
         }
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Edit: here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/Dutchlimits/pen/pmXKRK

Comment: Please show more of your HTML - we need an example that we can fiddle with. As it is, we would need to re-create the missing HTML ourselves to test your code, but who has time?

Comment: Got your answer

Comment: I've added a codepen: https://codepen.io/Dutchlimits/pen/pmXKRK

Answer (score 1):

I know your problem. You are appending more every time you switch cars. You can simply check your devtools and switch and see how you only keep adding elements which in turn adds more of them to hide/show. Thus your repeat.

```
 $("#tintbuilder-container").append("<div style='display:none;' id='"+ val + "' class='car hidecar'><div class='selectionlist'></div>"
        + "<div class='selectionprice'>Huidige selectie: &euro;<span class='"+ val + "price'>0</span>"
        + "<div><h3>Selectie</h3><ul class='" + val + "list'><ul></div></div>");
```

Which once you switch cars means in fact you have windows twice and the hidecar div and the slectionprice div. You keep adding more each time you change cars. So the function fires twice because now you have more. So after you switch once:

```
 $("#tintbuilder-container").append("<div style='display:none;' id='"+ val + "' class='car hidecar'><div class='selectionlist'></div>"
    + "<div class='selectionprice'>Huidige selectie: &euro;<span class='"+ val + "price'>0</span>"
    + "<div><h3>Selectie</h3><ul class='" + val + "list'><ul></div></div>");
```

and

```
$("#"+val+"").append("<a><div id='"+win+"-container'><div class='tint' id='" + win + "'></div></div></a>");
```

Will fire again because now you have 2 `$("#"+val+"").on`. Each time you switch cars because you only append and don't remove you get another link with that id so it fires an extra time.

Just run it in a codepen and you will see that you keep adding window links and div.hidecar elements which causes your repeating problem.

On your carselector change you have:

```
$('.hidecar').hide()
$('#' + this.value).show();
```

Since when you changed cars you added another:
`$('#' + this.value)`
and 
`$('.hidecar')`
You get another repeat. Those selectors now select two things after you change cars once, then 3 things after 2 and so on.

So you need a check before you keep appending to see if those div's are already there and instead change what is in them or simply check if they are there and remove them before appending what you have again.

**EDIT**:

Alright so I am actually going back to what I first said. Sorry that check I left did not work and it is because the if statement did not work.

However here is an answer that stops your divs from increasing which does solve both the windows and the car hide/show.

Simply pull the carselection change function out of the setup loop so that it doesn't keep appending more each time you change cars:

```
        $('#carselection').change(function () {
                $('.hidecar').hide()
                $('#' + this.value).show();
        });
```

Simply put that right above:
`jQuery.each( carlist, function( i, val, list ) {`
Then delete the extra `});` at the bottom of your js because you now have that change function closing above.

As seen here: https://codepen.io/ekr990011/pen/wbVVjB

Comment: Edited to updated answer after having done it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i will try your suggestion. Check out the codepen as well: https://codepen.io/Dutchlimits/pen/pmXKRK

Comment: Not working after adding your code

Im receiving this error :

index.html?editors=1100&key=iFrameKey-cf263e48-87d6-6f63-7a02-9c993583f559:479 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: Sorry I messed up that check I have a better answer. Forget that if statement I made and do what I did in this pen: https://codepen.io/ekr990011/pen/wbVVjB
   I explained it in my EDIT of my answer. You should be good to go it solves both the repeating car divs and the window links.